# Android - Draw badges on MenuItems

Tags: android

I would like to display badges on menu items. How do I do it?

Basically, I don't want to draw or use the canvas to do so.

Comment: do you only want the images associated with the your menu items..

Comment: yes, A bitmap and a number on top right corner

Comment: If you desire the things as that of messages icon.. Then it is complex task and need to be handled via Custom widget,, You can simple have an button with image in that form with certain text and gravity as top|right etc

Comment: @AgarwalShankar did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options menu in Android can be customized to set the background or change the text appearance. The background and text color in the menu couldn’t be changed using themes and styles.

The Android source code (`data\res\layout\icon_menu_item_layout.xml`) uses a custom item of class “com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItem”View for the menu layout. We can make changes in the above class to customize the menu. To achieve the same, use the `LayoutInflater` factory class and set the background and text color for the view.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (name .equalsIgnoreCase(“com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView”)) {
                try{
                    LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // Set the background drawable
                            view .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_ac_menu_background);

                            // Set the text color
                            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                }
                catch (InflateException e) {
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: This helped me but it was not what exactly i was looking

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a `LayerListDrawable`, with your regular icon as the first layer and your badge as the second layer, then use that with `setIcon()` on `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Menuitem has an attribute icon, for example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mi_main_preferences"
        android:title="@string/cmd_preferences"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Above example uses system icon (preferences menu).

Comment: But how can i have bbadge on it

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is not good. Is there difference between icon and badge?